# Strange "sticky footer" issue (scroll bar and div overlap)

Tags: html, css

Based on [this article](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html) I want to make sticky footer on my project. Please take a look [at this link.](http://www.alfaicra.az/)

I can't understand why I'm getting vertical scrollbar, and why `#page` div goes under `#footer`

Answer (score 4):

Your footer has a 1px border-top; your container has a 1px border; your nav has a margin-top... all of these affect the vertical height, so the overall height is pushed to more than 100% => vertical scrollbar.

You need to account for that when you set your padding/margin to offset for the extra pixels. Additionally, you're giving the footer element padding/margin. What you should do is use the footer element as a wrapper and then create an element within it with the proper padding/margin.

Here's how you can make it work...

1 change `#nav` styles to padding: `padding: 10px 0 0 0;`

2 get rid of the 1px border on your `#container`

3 change your footer to this...

```
<div id="footer">
  <div id="footer-content">
    © 2012 Code Arts
  </div>
</div>
```

4 change your footer css to this:

```
#footer {
  border-top: 1px solid #C9E0ED;
  height: 53px; /* 20px padding-top + 20px padding-bottom + 13px line-height */
  margin-top: -54px; /* height + 1px border-top */
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
}
#footer-content {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 13px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: tested all off them. No success! Please tell me what exactly to change?

Comment: Look at this link please http://goo.gl/rAi6x Why #page goes under footer? http://screencast.com/t/neWzfwS0XUr

Comment: because you're giving the container a background image and its height is 100%

Comment: that's a different question... accept my answer for this question since we fixed your vertical scroll bar issue and then ask another question outlining this background problem

Comment: re-read my question `and why #page div goes under #footer?` İ already asked this

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
z-index: 2;
```

...on #footer.

Also, what in the world is margin-top:-32767px; supposed to do!?